Inherit from type parameter
Is it possible to achieve following functionality in typescript?
export interface Foo<T> extends T {
}

As such this produces an error
An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

which I tried circumventing with
export interface Foo<T extends Object> extends T {
}

which produces following:
Interface 'Foo<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'T'.
  'Foo<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Object'.

How does this apply to my code? What difference does this message try to point out?

When you need it, you can just use the intersection Foo & T

see linked q/a above. you can't write interface Foo<T> extends T no matter what T is constrained to, since T can always have more properties than the constraint, and therefore it doesn't have statically known keys.  Your attempt to fix it with extends Object doesn't help. That second error message is confusing, but it's essentially an XY problem, since you're not going to fix the problem by trying to make T assignable to Foo<T>
